# VBScript: FormatNumber() / rounding issue

Tags: vbscript, rounding, output

```
dim num

num = 4895390000000005 

msgbox FormatNumber(num, 0, -2, -2, false)
```

the output is 4895390000000010

instead of    4895390000000005

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your "number" is larger than integer, declare as decimal works for me:

```
Dim num As Decimal

num = 4895390000000005

MsgBox(FormatNumber(num, 0, -2, -2, False))
```

Comment: Are you using vb or vbscript? I don't think you can declare variants in vbscript using the 'as' syntax. It will throw an 'expected end of statement' error

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example using com visible .net class.

```
With CreateObject("System.IO.StringWriter")
    .Write_7 4895390000000005
    MsgBox .GetStringBuilder().ToString()
End With
```

And here is reference [link](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Interop-Using-NET-from-VBScript-m26652.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

True, if you're looking to do this in plain old vbscript (.vbs) you could easily create a library to handle math functions and types not available in vbscript. Below is a short working example. Let me know if it's helpful.

--In visual studio:

```
Imports System

Public Class mathLibrary

    Public Function roundNumber(number As String) As String

        Dim roundedNumber As String = ""
        Dim largeNumber As Decimal = 0

        If IsNumeric(number) Then

            largeNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(number)

            roundedNumber = FormatNumber(largeNumber, 0, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.False)

        End If

        Return roundedNumber

    End Function

End Class
```

--now update your .vbs:

```
dim mathLib
set mathLib = CreateObject("sampleMathLibrary.mathLibrary")

Dim num
num = "4895390000000005"

msgbox mathLib.roundNumber(num)
```